# WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application when installing libtiff

Tags: python, winapi, anaconda, libtiff

I have been attempting to install libtiff for python 2.7 using Anaconda 4.2.0 terminal:

`conda install libtiff`

`pip install libtiff`

I installed the libtiff library (GnuWin32) and have specified the directory of libtiff3.dll on my environment variable PATH. However when trying to import libtiff in Python I receive the following error:

`File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)`

`WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

I have been searching for a solution to no avail. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you try `where libtiff3.dll` from a command prompt?

Comment: Yes, it's in the appropriate directory: C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\libtiff3.dll

Comment: Typical 32-/64-bit mismatch. You are either trying to load a 64-bit module into a 32-bit process or vice versa. Use a tool like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to figure out, which module is failing to load.

Comment: I found the libtiff3.dll file using Process Monitor, and under the Process tab it's architecture is 64-bit. Using platform.architecture() in IPython console, Python is also running in 64-bit. Am I missing something here?

Comment: 32/64 is the most likely. Debug using dependency walker in profile mode.